# How to link the plus sign (add new record) to go to another web page

Tags: jqgrid

How do I link the plus sign at the bottom of the grid to go to a different web page as opposed to pop up a dialogue?

Currently there is a default dialogue popping up but I need it to link to a different web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
setupPager: function () {
        $('#myGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#myPager',
        {
            addtitle: 'Add',            
            add: true,
            addfunc: function () {
                window.open(newpageurl);
            },
            //..more options go here
        }
         );
    },
```